# How can I use an axios get call inside a Context provider in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-context

I want to make a call to get the user information and use it in different components throughout the application, so I am using react.Context and I managed to move a string around between components but when I tried to use the axios.get I was not able to get the data to another component, here is the context code:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const userContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = (props) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    const res = axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config)
    return(
    <userContext.Provider value= { res }>{props.children}</userContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

can someone please tell me what I did wrong here

Comment: Why are you making an API call inside the context provider? You should make the call inside a component and dispatch an action that updates the global state with the data you're fetching from the API.

Answer (score 6):

It would be more manageable if you could handle the `state` in hassle free way. Instead of passing the `res` which I reckoned going to be your state, directly to the `Provider`. Which I think, in time, if you have more than one `state` you want to add to your `User` context. You gonna need to pass them too as `value`. That would not be flexible.

I would suggest you to manage them like so:-

1. Having dedicated `User` context folder: `src/contexts/User`

- `src/contexts/User/UserContext` (creating `User` context)

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();
```

- `src/contexts/User/UserReducer` (handle `state` update)

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      };
    case "SET_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload.error,
        message: action.payload.message
      };
    case "SET_LOADING":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

- `src/contexts/User/UserAction` (handle `action` done to `state`. Basically anything that you need to make the changes to your `state`)

```
import axios from "axios";

// Set Loading
export const setLoading = (dispatch, status) =>
  dispatch({ type: "SET_LOADING", payload: status });

// Set Error
export const setError = (dispatch, error) =>
  dispatch({
    type: "SET_ERROR",
    payload: { error: error.status, message: error.message }
  });

// Set User (get user info)
export const getUser = async dispatch => {
  setLoading(dispatch, true);

  // do fetch
  await axios
    .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`)
    .then(res => {
      const result = res.data;

      // set user info
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_USER",
        payload: result
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      const result = error;

      // set error if has any
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_ERROR",
        payload: {
          error: true,
          message: result
        }
      });
    });
};
```

- `src/contexts/User/UserState` (handle `state` initialization. You can later add more or initialize more state in `const initialState` below if you have any. Plus you don't need to add more `value` in future tho.)

```
import React, { useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import UserReducer from "./UserReducer";

export const useUser = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);
  return [state, dispatch];
};

export const UserState = ({ children }) => {
  const initialState = {
    user: {},
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    message: ""
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(UserReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        state: state,
        dispatch: dispatch
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then you can use them like so:-

1. Make sure to `encapsulate` any `component` thet you wanna use the `User` context (this will be in `App.js`)

- `App.js`:-

```
import React from "react";
import { UserState } from "./contexts/User/UserState";
import Demo from "./Demo";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <UserState>
      <Demo />
    </UserState>
  );
}
```

2. You can use any `state` `initialized` in `UserState` by using `useState`:-

- `Demo.js` (`App.js` child component):-

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useUser } from "./contexts/User/UserState";
import { getUser, setLoading } from "./contexts/User/UserAction";
import "./style.css";

const Demo = () => { 
  const [userState, userDispatch] = useUser();
  const { user, loading, error, message } = userState;

  // get user info handler
  const getUserInfoHandler = async () => {
    await getUser(userDispatch);
    setLoading(userDispatch, false);
  };

  // get user info
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfoHandler();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error && <p>{message}</p>}
      <p>User name: {user.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

You may see the working code here in [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-suz8pb?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thank you so much for the long explanation, but I do not think I explained my question correctly, I already have an authentication system and after I get the JWT I use it to get the user information, but I want to use this information in another page and that is why I have been looking into context, I have been looking for a while and I understand how to make a context and a provider but I do not understand how can I update the context data inside a class based react component "class ..... extendes React.component", can you please show me how to use it ?? Thanks

Comment: Thanks A lot, how to make PUT POST request can you modify answer to add that as well much appreciated

Comment: @AshishKamble. You can refer to this example I made here in [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uezmqz?file=src%2Fcontexts%2FPost%2FPostAction.js). Hope it helps